# JSON sorting in Java

Tags: java, json, sorting, bigdata

I have a huge JSON file (400MB). I want to sort by TimeStamp. Do you have any idea, how can I do this?

I created a program with the loop, which is sorted small files, but my file is the too big, and I got an infinitive loop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCvCu.png)

Comment: Please post a useful example of the JSON content as text, not as an image. Also post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Just be aware that some JSON libraries are built up on hash maps or dictionaries where a [reordering might not take effect (last paragraph)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4). The only element in a JSON that guarantees ordering is an array. The best workaround here would be to utilize a sorted set of keys that you ship along with the actual JSON data IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Use the library [big-sorter](https://github.com/davidmoten/big-sorter) as below.

```java
Sorter 
  .serializer(Serializer.jsonArray()) 
  .comparator((x, y) -> 
    x.get("time").asText().compareTo(y.get("time").asText())) 
  .input(new File("input.json")) 
  .output(new File("sorted.json")) 
  .sort();
```

With this method I sorted 10 million records in a 440MB file in 54s with max heap set at 64MB (`-Xmx64m`).

Answer (score 0):

I would create an object T implemeting Comparable. The object T should representing an entry in the Json file.

I would then load the Json into a list of object T using Gson.

Then you can do a Collections.sort on your list.

Comment: wow, such as simple and straight forward solution, may be you should ask the OP for that 400mb json and you must try your solution first. btw, I haven't downvoted your post till now